# Amortized analysis and the potential method

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

To my understanding to use the potential method to get the amortized cost of an operation the following conditions need to be satisfied:

- $\Phi (D_{0}) = 0$
- $\Phi (D_{i}) \geq 0$ for all $i \geq 0$
- $\Phi (D_{i}) = \Phi (D_{i-1}) + \operatorname{cost}_{\text{am}}(op_{i}) - \operatorname{cost}_{\text{real}}(op_{i})$

However, I'm seeing a solution to a problem that has a potential function such that $\Phi (D_{0}) \ne 0$. How could this still work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial potential, per se, doesn't really matter. The important part is the interaction between the first two rules: the potential is never allowed to drop below its initial value (except perhaps in the middle of an operation).

#### Edit:

The technique being used does not appear to be quite the same sort of amortized analysis you're thinking of that guarantees that any sequence of $k$ operations will take no more than $\sum a_i [0<i\le k]$ real time. Rather, a very specific sequence of a specific number of operations is being performed. This allows certain things to be done in the analysis that would otherwise be forbidden. Note that the extra $n$ is tacked on to the total time at the end, in the second hint.

Comment: The question I have, the potential does in fact drop below the initial potential...

Comment: @user99748, that's a pretty strange analysis. Have you looked around for errata?

Comment: There is a copy of the problem here: http://tinyurl.com/mtlf364

Comment: Initial potential is n, and to me it does go below n for subsequent operations.

Comment: @user99748, see the edit.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I see your point about this being a predefined sequence of operations we are carrying out, but I still don't understand why we can have the potential go below n (the initial potential)... what allows us to do this?

Comment: @user99748, I think you could probably reframe it in stricter terms by adding the number of of operations that have already been performed into the potential, but the potential is really just an accounting method—you can pretty much make it anything you like as long as the proof you use it to construct ends up valid. In other words, just define the function as described, don't think of it strictly as a "potential", but go through the analysis and prove that the invariants you actually *need* are satisfied.

Comment: Side note: much more discipline in applying the accounting rules tends to be needed when analyzing lazy data structures—changes that seem perfectly harmless, or even beneficial, can turn out to break the amortized bounds in subtle ways. See Okasaki for details.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I was able to show that it's still sound mathematically to myself.